# Reflection doesn't get the correct value (could it be a .NET framework bug?)

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, reflection, watch

I have a very strange issue with a Reflection.
When I try to get the value of a field, which contains list of objects, I get the `list.Count == 0`. When I check these values in the watch window during debugging, afterwards I get the `list.Count > 0` with the same Reflection method.
There are no multithreading between the checks (Thread ID is the same) and no operations being performed, which would clear and refill the list again. I could not reproduce the issue on the clean (testing) project.
I use .NET framework 4.0 for compatibility reasons and the following logics in the code:

```
Type t = cmd.GetType();
FieldInfo[] fi = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
object[] o1 = null;
if (fi != null)
{
    o1 = new object[fi.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < o1.Length; i++)
    {
        o1[i] = fi[i].GetValue(cmd);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if someone had similar issues and could share with ideas what could have gone wrong and maybe there are solutions how to workaround. To be honest there were few more cases where I could observe the inconsistencies between the debugging information and what the program actually does. For example, once I've encountered a situation where the debug tool had shown the result `true` but the `if` clause skipped the line as it would have been `false` result.

Comment: Just because the thread ID is the same, it doesn't mean that you don't have multithreading issues.

Comment: " I could not reproduce the issue on the clean (testing) project" - then you need to work harder on creating a repro. Perhaps instead of starting from a clean project, take a copy of your existing project and *remove* elements whilst ensuring it still exhibits the problem. (Also, for the bit at the end, it almost always is a result of needing to clean/rebuild or working with out of date source files)

Comment: You have many self-made conclusions which we aren't able to check (without [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Can you prove them one by one? E.g. this mysterious `if` story? Maybe you are monitoring another object than the one currently used by your code (can be checked with `GetHashCode` easily).

Comment: No, it isn't a framework bug.  Those are exceedingly rare.

Comment: Yes, I agree that thread id does not ensure that some other process from other thread doesn't interfere but this is definitely not the case. I did recompile but the result didn't change. In most cases the problems lie in the code. But in this case the only difference is that I either check with the watch window or not. The breakpoints didn't change and that's what confuses me.